# MVC - Bootstrap 3 - Upload Image - How to display immediately?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC 5 Bootstrap 3 form with a File input control to allow the user to upload an image. It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Load Photo", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine. But what I would like to do is to immediately display the image just selected on the form without first requiring the user submit the form. Is this possible?

Comment: i mostly use this plugin to upload and display the file without refreshing page:http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**Jquery File Upload Plugin**](http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) for this purpose. I mostly use this plugin as it uploads file asynchronously page refresh and i used to return file path after file upload and display it on the page.

It is compatible with asp.net mvc.

Here is a [**DEMO Project**](http://powerdotnetcore.com/wp-content/uploads/TestAjaxUpload.rar) as well.